# include SSI in javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ssi

based on the query string, I include a portion of a different code SSI in the footer page.
My query string for example:

?headId=520&genderType=2

?headId=600&genderType=1

```
function GetQueryStringParams(sParam){

    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}​

$(document).ready(function() {

    var genderM = GetQueryStringParams('genderType');
    var genderF = GetQueryStringParams('genderType');

    if ( genderM == 2 ) {
        $('#adv').html('<!--#include virtual="genderM.shtml"-->')
    } else if (genderF == 1 ){
        $('#adv').html('<!--#include virtual="genderF.shtml"-->')
    };

});
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: You're trying to include your include *after* the page has been processed by the server.

Comment: SSI stands for "Server-Side Includes".  *Server*-side.  This means they run on the server.  They run on the server as it's generating the page to be sent to the client.  Once it's on the client, it's too late.  You need to check the queryStrings on the *server* not the client.

Answer (score 1):

You can just put the SSI inside an html page e.g. anotherpage.html

```
<!--#include virtual="genderM.shtml"-->
```

Then load the page using javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "anotherpage.html",
    success: function(data) {
        $('#adv').html(data);
    },
    dataType: 'html'
});
```